# Listing errors in experimental section

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am fairly new to report writing, and am currently writing an experimental section.

Obviously we are required to list measurements, but I was wondering whether or not we are supposed to list the corresponding errors with these?

E.g. 5 mL $\pm$ 0.01 mL sodium hydroxide was added to...

Or if not, why this isn't included?

Comment: 5 mL ±0.01 mL  doesn't make much sense. I guess you meant $\pu{(5.00 \pm 0.01) mL}$ or $\pu{5.00(1) mL}$. If you speak German and have access to DINs, I would suggest to have a look at [DIN 1319](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1319) series and DIN 1319-3 + 1319-4 in particular. Otherwise any lab manual explains the measurements handling more or less OK.

Comment: Ask your supervisors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on the context.

For example if we are talking about synthetic chemistry the exact amount often isn't relevant, for example in case of solvents for the reaction. It doesn't really matter if you do it in 200 mL or 198 or 201 mL. Therefore no one cares to measure it exactly in the first place and no one really cares about those errors, especially since you would need to measure temperature as well.

In other cases, like many analytical methods, you need to know the exact amount which was used and in those cases you should definitely include errors.

In the end you need to include it if it's relevant information, it's common to omit it if it's not relevant.